# Kendo - any way to know if a model field is dirty?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I understand that we can know if a model is dirty.

Something like this

`$("#listview").data("kendoListView").dataSource.at(0).dirty` would return true or false.

Is there any way we can know if a field in the model is dirty ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is **not** possible to tell which field is dirty, just that the model itself is dirty.

You can find a way to work around it. I suppose you can do something like this:

**NOTE: THIS IS NOT A VERY GOOD WAY OF DOING THIS, BUT IT WILL WORK**

```
change: function (e) {
    var index = this.select().index();
    var dataItem = this.dataSource.at(index);

    //will create an object in the model, you can name it whatever you want
    dataItem.addressIsDirty = true;
}
```

Then later you can do a check:

```
var model = $("#listview").data("kendoListView").dataSource.at(0);

if(model.addressIsDirty) {
    //do stuff
}
```

If that field is `undefined` then it will skip that conditional statement.

This isn't pretty, and now you'll probably have to keep track of the new objects you're adding, but you'll be able to keep track of dirty fields.